# Unbound imagecontrol ONLY show First image when imagelink is added in a 1:N relation

Tags: image, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Background:
Entry is via a subform for adding/showing/linking images.
I do not want to store the image files within my DB, the image folder is separate. The DB will grow rather large in time.

I have created a click-control enabling a popup for user to browse and click on the imagePATH to be added in a Bound Textfield (called Bildadress, no not misspelled in My country, *Grin* ) in the subform.
See code below.

Then I add a new unbound Image-control and specify its Controlsource = the Textfield mentioned above.
For the firs image this works wonderful, but for the following the Image-control returns NULL (not show att all). The data in the Textfield updates as it should.

**Will the 2nd stage only work in a 1:1 relationship OR can I (with your help) use VBA code to make this work?**

OPTIMAL would be to get this to work and also a 2nd Bound Textfield just displaying the actual image file name. .

I hope someone out there have encountered this problem who also didnt want to use Attachment to store the files within the databae.

CODE:

```
Private Sub AddFilePath_Click()
Call Selectfile

End Sub

Public Function Selectfile() As String   
Dim Fd As FileDialog   
Set Fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)   
With Fd        
    .AllowMultiSelect = False    
    .Title = "Välj önskad fil"     
    If .Show = True Then    
        Selectfile = .SelectedItems(1)    
        Me.Bildadress = Selectfile    

    Else
        Exit Function
    End If
End With
    Set Fd = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a bound textbox that holds the image-path then you can use

`Me.Imagecontrol.Picture = Me.BoundTextControl.Value`

to load the picture into an unbound image control. In your case that would be something like

```
If .Show = True Then    
    Me.Bildadress.value = .SelectedItems(1)    
    Me.Bild.Picture = Me.Bildadress.value
Else
```

It would be best to also load the respective picture in the OnCurrent Event.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.Bild.Picture = Me.Bildadress.value    
End Sub
```

However, keep in mind that access is a one-file-database and you break that paradigm when using links to external files where the files would belong into the DB.

Comment: Thanx for input Johanness. The one-file-db issue has been an ongoing topic with employer :) I will try your suggestions. I have also been doing some calculations and if they keep image size at max 256kb then they should be able to more than tripple their current no of pics before ever reaching even 1GB total for images. Taking this into consideraton, would u recommend a "standard" OLE solution instead, and do u by any chance have a good one, or perhaps the "new" Attachment solution, though the usr DO need to see both the path AND individual image name.jpg in one bound TEXT control each.

Comment: Sorry if these Q:s and thoughts seem abit "I'll use U" but I am coming down with a flu of some kind and struggling to get this done b4 X-mas holidays *GRIN* I am VERY grateful for all support. //baronlime

Comment: I dont think keeping everything in the DB is always a good thing. Just make sure everybody who deals with the data knows that the db-file alone isn't the whole data. When I deal with large images or soundfiles I try to have the db-file in a specific directory with a subdirectory named data (or similar) where all the pictures are in. Better even: split the DB into frontend and backend and put the backend into the same folder as the images (and nothing else). In that case you also dont have to have the whole path in the textfield - just use CurrentProject.Path & "\data\" & Me.Bildadress.value